# Change find results window background color in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When installing Visual Studio 2015 I chose the blue theme.  Overall I've very happy with this choice as is resembles the design of what I has previously been using in VS2010.  The one thing that bugs me is that the find results content area is light blue instead of white.  How can I change the background color of the finds results window to white?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps someone else.

I found the setting in Tools>Options> Environment>Font and Colors then select "Find Results Window" in the drop down and then change the "Item background" via that drop down.

[image: screenshot of options window]